# Return from HashMap<String, String> when no key

Tags: java

What does a `HashMap<String,String>` return when I call map.get("key") and I don't have an entry with the key "key" in the HashMap?

Comment: Read the docs ... http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get(java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 123):

It returns `null`. It's written in the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29).

> Returns:
>       the value to which the specified key is mapped, or null if this map contains no mapping for the key

The first thing to do when you have such a specific question is to consult the documentation. Java APIs are documented reasonably well and tell you what is returned, what exceptions are thrown and what each argument means.

Answer (score 16):

You can:

Check in your IDE

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("foo", "fooValue");
System.out.println(map.get("bar")); // null
```

Check [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get%28java.lang.Object%29) - HashMap get() method description:

> Returns the value to which the
>   specified key is mapped, or null if
>   this map contains no mapping for the
>   key.

Comment: again HashMap<String> is not possible in standard java library, unless you have created your own HashMap, it should be with two type arguments like Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>() or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Careful -
If you initialize it using

```
Map.of(key, val, key, val)
```

and then do a

```
get('key-that-isnt-there')
```

then you'll get a null pointer exception.